# Проблема с логическим выражением в обработке нажатия кнопки javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу приложение которое проверяет логин и пароль, но возникла проблема при проверке условия когда пользователь оставляет поля ввода логина или пароля пустыми. В чем моя ошибка?

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
public class Main extends Application{
Label lbUsername;
Label lbPassword;
Label lbInfoPanel;
Button btnLogIn;
TextField flUsername;
PasswordField flPassword;
String Username;
String Password;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public void start(Stage myStage){
    myStage.setTitle("Login");
    FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10,10);
    rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene myScene1 = new Scene(rootNode, 300, 300);
    myStage.setScene(myScene1);
    lbUsername = new Label("Enter a Username");
    lbPassword = new Label("Enter a password");
    btnLogIn = new Button("Log in");
    flUsername = new TextField();
    flPassword = new PasswordField();
    lbInfoPanel = new Label();
    Username = new String();
    Password = new String();
    btnLogIn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Username = flUsername.getText();
            Password = flPassword.getText();
            if ((Username == "") || (Username == null) || (Password == "") || (Password == null))
                lbInfoPanel.setText("You forget to enter username of password");

        }
    });
    rootNode.getChildren().addAll(lbUsername, flUsername, lbPassword, flPassword,
            btnLogIn,lbInfoPanel);
    myStage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы неправильно сравниваете строки.

Оператор `==` сравнивает **ссылки на объекты**, а **не содержимое** этих объектов.

В `Java` содержимое строк сравнивается с помощью метода `String.equals(...)`.

Предположим, Вам нужно сравнить две строки `String strOne = "SomeTextOne"` и `String strTwo = "SomeTextTwo"`. Делается это следующим образом:

```
boolean b = strOne.equals(strTwo);
```

В итоге, метод `equals(...)` вернет:

- `true`, если строки `strOne` и `strTwo` лексикографически равны;
- `false`, если строки `strOne` и `strTwo` лексикографически НЕ равны.

Отдельно выделять память под строки (`new String()`) здесь не нужно, так как метод `getText()` возвращает ссылку на объект типа `String` (или `null` (!)).

Так же, для проверки содержимого строк на *пустоту*, можно воспользоваться методом `String.isEmpty()` вместо `equals("")`.

В итоге, получится что-то такое:

```
if (Username == null || Password == null) {
    lbInfoPanel.setText("Something going wrong");
} else if (Username.isEmpty() || Password.isEmpty()) {
    lbInfoPanel.setText("You forget to enter username of password");
}
```

Вообще, я несколько сомневаюсь, нужна ли в данном случае проверка на `null`, [так как](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.java#TextInputControl.TextProperty.0textIsNull). Но лучше пусть она будет и не понадобится, чем ее не будет и...

---

А еще, есть такая штука, как [пул строк](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), благодаря которой, в **некоторых случаях**, строки гарантированно представлены одним и тем же объектом. Но это бывает очень редко, и пользоваться оператором `==` для сравнения содержимого строк нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки текстовых данных существуют специальные методы в Java

попробуйте заменить ваше условие на этот:

```
if (Username.isEmpty() || Password.isEmpty()){
            lbInfoPanel.setText("You forget to enter username of password");
    }
```

Метод `.isEmpty();` вернет вам `true` если строка будет пустой,
а для сранения друг с другом строки используется метод `.equals(str2);`

```
//вот пример:
String name1 = "User";
String name2 = "Login";
String name3 = "User";
String name4 = "login";

//Присвоется значение True так как строки идеентичны
boolean check1 = name1.equals(name3);

//Присвоется значение False так как строки Login и login не идеентичны, ведь не забываем то что Java чувствителен к регистру.
boolean check2 = name2.equals(name4);

//присвоется значение False так как строка не пустая и содержит какой-то текст
boolean check3 = name3.isEmpty();
```